# Double XP Weekend doubles weapon XP?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Now, I know that double XP and double Weapon XP are different, but:

Is "Double XP WEEKEND" the same as "Double Weapon XP"?

I know "Double XP" does not double weapon XP. But, does "Double XP WEEKEND" double your weapon XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately it does not. Only the experience doubles.